# custom login for firebase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have to implement a chat platform using firebase and swift.

I know how to create a user using emailid :

```
    firebase.createUser(emailTextField, password: passwordTextField.text) { (error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.displayMessage(error)
        } else{
            print("New user created")
            self.requestUsername()
        }
    }
```

But I am not taking any email id or other accounts. I want to create a custom user. For that they have mentioned to use the secure JWT Token and then use this :

```
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/")
ref.authWithCustomToken(AUTH_TOKEN, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
    if error != nil {
        println("Login failed! \(error)")
    } else {
        println("Login succeeded! \(authData)")
    }
})
```

But they have not mentioned how to generate secure JWT Token in swift. 
Anyone know?

Here is the link i referred:
[How to login in firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/custom.html)

Comment: Some feedback below, because it didn't fit nicely into the comment box. But I'm going to close to vote, since: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably noticed, there is no helper library from Firebase for minting custom tokens on iOS. There is however a set of instructions on how to mint tokens here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/custom.html#section-tokens-without-helpers

Minting tokens in a client-app is in general a **VERY** bad idea, since it requires that you have your Firebase's secret in your app, where any user can find it.